# eshell insert arguments from previous commands

Tags: eshell

I use `M-.` a lot to insert arguments of previous commands when using zsh/bash.  Is there a built-in equivalent for `eshell`?

I did a GH code search, and saw this was implemented by [em-last](https://github.com/Henry/dot-emacs/blob/de960ff5d63b477cfa942b7a7fb1ad10f453a293/lisp/em-last.el) and [em-zle](https://github.com/emacsattic/em-zle), though these packages are 10+ years old, so I thought something equivalent might have been added to eshell in that time (also neither appear to be distributed by a package archive).

Comment: Can't you use `comint-previous-input` ? Normally bound to `<C-up>` and `M-p`

Comment: Unfortunately `eshell-previous-matching-input-from-input` (bound to `M-p` - I don't think eshell is derived from comint) inserts the whole command, I just want args.